# Is it appropriate to send an introduction letter after applying for the job?

Tags: applications, networking

I would like to send an email to introduce myself to someone who works at a company I'm interested in joining. I applied for the job about a week ago, however, and I'm afraid such an email would not be appropriate now.

My motivation for sending the letter comes from genuine interest to learn more about the position, and a desire to network and introduce myself.

Is it appropriate to reach out at this point? And are there things I should mention? (Having already applied, for example).

I'm yet to hear back from the company, other than a canned response that they'll get back to me in a few weeks. And the said person isn't involved in HR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something to say, you should write the letter, **better late than never**. Mention that you have already applied, and for what position. And consider explaining why do you think you're writing to the right person:

- was this person mentioned in the job offer? No questions here, it's your guy.
- did someone tell you about him? In that case, it may be a good idea to disclose that reference.
- did you find the contact on the company's website, or somewhere else on the web? Then, why do you think this person will have any decisive power over your application? Is he the leader of the group which has opened the position? Tell them that, it shows your interest in the company.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this what cover letters are for? You write a specific letter to the company and submit it with your resume.

Otherwise what you said sounds uncommon. I wouldn't be surprised if it met a lot of opposition depending on the industry you're applying for since it sounds like you're phishing for organizational information.

Comment: I would simply ping the HR contact and explain you are still interested in the position. Personally I wouldn't go beyond that asking them for specific individuals to contact.

Comment: In general, I think you have offered good advice. In my case, however, this is a modern and young IT startup. There are open, and encourage reaching out. I think being honest about my intentions and reaching out is a positive thing. Thanks for your answer.